# ERROR: Deploy VueJS App in Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, vue.js, webpack, firebase-hosting

I have a vue application, I install firebase tools and upload the application to firebase hosting, the first time all done and I make `npm run build` and `firebase deploy`, but when I realise any change, and later do `npm run serve` or `build` or `firebase deploy` I have the next error:

```
Template execution failed: ReferenceError: features is not defined

  ReferenceError: features is not defined

  - index.html:4 eval
    [.]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/loader.js!./public/index.html:4:10

  - index.html:7 module.exports
    [.]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/loader.js!./public/index.html:7:3

  - index.js:284 Promise.resolve.then
    [real]/[html-webpack-plugin]/index.js:284:18


  - next_tick.js:188 process._tickCallback
    internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7
```

Any idea? I don't know why this problem succeed. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

When you installed firebase tools, it generated a public folder for you. Inside that public folder, there is an index.html file(this file is the cause of the error). Just delete everything inside that index.html file, then replace with your own content.

Answer (score 3):

In firebase.json file in hosting change `"public": "public"` to `"public": "dist"`
When you installed firebase, it changed the file public/index.html, the original version looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon.ico">
    <title>hello-world-vuetify</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@latest/css/materialdesignicons.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but hello-world-vuetify doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Replace the content, it worked for me